# disable browser refresh button for my html/php certain pages

Tags: javascript

I knew i can disable f5 by below code. But I am looking for to disable browser refresh button (which most expert says, it can not be possible), Therefore I want to knew is there any way by which my php page do not refresh when I click on refresh button of the browser.
here is below code for to disable f5 button which I copied from stack overflow

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableF5(e) { if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116 || (e.which || e.keyCode) == 82) e.preventDefault(); };

$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on("keydown", disableF5);
});
</script>
```

Comment: no it's not possible as that's inbuilt feature of google chrome browser.

what you can do is tell what exactly is it that you're trying to solve by disabling refresh button. how will refreshing affect your website in a way you don't want? we can think about trying to solve that.

Comment: actually i have phphtml form with mysql database table, when i submit my form, the form save successfully, and action = abc.php page return with post value of first page, when I refresh abc.php, the data again submitted in database. I knew i can handle this with primary key but i have multiple table where primary or unique key is not possible

Comment: you could try redirecting user to a new page after form has been submitted.

just by the way, are you using ajax or traditional form submission? please share the whole form code and JS if you're using that to send the form